# Laravel 4.2 Model Name from ModelNotFoundException

Tags: php, laravel, exception, model-view-controller, model

Afternoon SO,

I've been trying to workout if there is a way to find out/pass along the model name when a ::findOrFail() query executes the ModelNotFoundException error.

This has become an issue for me recently in an application in which orders may be deleted by the end user. If an somebody has bookmarked the URL or otherwise tries to visit the URL associated with the deleted order I throw an exception and show a 404 page.

Model declaration:

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletingTrait;

class Order extends Eloquent
{
    use SoftDeletingTrait;
    ...
}
```

FindOrFail:

```
$order = $this->organisation->orders()->with('events', 'events.user', ...)->where('id', $id)->firstOrFail();
```

Exception Handler

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\ModelNotFoundException;

App::error(function(ModelNotFoundException $e)
{
    return Redirect::route('404')->withMessage(modelNameHere);
});
```

Is there a way to distinguish which model has thrown the exception and show a custom error with this in mind.

Thanks

Comment: did you add 'use' for a model name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is **yes**. It is very simple to find out which model caused the exception. Once you catch the **ModelNotFoundException** object, you can call **getModel()** on it to get the classname of the model that could be found.

Comment: Thank you very much, this is exactly what I was looking for.
If you happen to know where this can be found in the documentation could you point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

1. Validation in Controller, 
   for example:

   $post = Post::find($post_id);

   if( !isset($post) )
   {
       abort(404);
   }
2. Use FindOrFail,
   for example:

   ```
   try
   {
       $post = Post::FindOrFail($id)
   }

   catch (NotFoundHttpException $e)
   {
       abort(404);
   }
   ```

for View, Laravel use views/errors/404.blade.php 
you can customize it as you want.